# Python CLoader and Unicode

Tags: python, json, unicode, yaml

When using CLoader as the Loader for yaml.load, it will not process unicode in my json. However, when I use the default loader the json is loaded fine.

I can work around this by catching the exception and loading it without CLoader.
Has anyone any experience with this that knows of a solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import yaml
from yaml import CLoader as Loader1
from yaml import Loader
data_string = "\"nickname\": \"Stringhere \ud83d\udcaf\""
print "Loading with default loader"
json_data = yaml.load(data_string, Loader=Loader)
print "Loading with CLoader"
json_data = yaml.load(data_string, Loader=Loader1)



yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while parsing a quoted scalar
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 13
found invalid Unicode character escape code
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 27
```

Comment: What is the content of `data_string`? Replace the read operation with a hardcoded string to get closer to the required MCVE. Why don't you use Python 3? Also, have you tried loading the file and converting it to a Python `unicode` object, using the proper encoding, of course?

Comment: The contents of data_string is too large to paste, but the offending string is "nickname": "Stringhere \ud83d\udcaf".
I don't want to use Python 3.  I have not tried to convert it to a Python unicode object.

Comment: data_string = unicode(data_string, "utf-8")
This results in the same exception.  CLoader doesn't want to work with unicode.

Comment: libyaml doesn't support surrogate pairs, so those `\u` escapes are already rejected by the parser. I think this should be fixed, though.

Comment: also, please don't post informations about your code/data in comments. first try to create a minimal example: [mcve] you already know the problematic part of your input, so it should be easy to create a test case out of it that people can simply copy and run

Comment: @tinita I'm not really sure what you are implying with "libyaml doesn't support surrogate pairs", and "I think this should be fixed though".  Seems conflicting. In addition, I am showing you it works with the default loader, but not CLoader.  I changed my example above to be minimal, complete, and verifiable.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Hope that helps

Comment: "contents of data_string is too large to paste" -- it's completely fine to extract a part of it so that the effect becomes visible, so what you did is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

The PyYAML CLoader uses libyaml under the hood. And libyaml will reject such escapes. Only some `\u` escapes are supported, but not those which build a surrogate pair.

The PyYAML python parser (which is used by the loader imported with `Loader`), however, parses this, but still doesn't convert it to a unicode character.

The YAML 1.1/1.2 specifications don't explicitly mention surrogate pairs.
However, since YAML 1.2 is a superset of JSON, and JSON supports this, I think libyaml should support this, too. (It targets YAML 1.1, but since it will currently simply return an error, it wouldn't hurt to add support for that.)

I created an issue for libyaml: https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/issues/110

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

The JSON RFC mentions surrogate pairs in Chapter 7:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7

Comment: Hmmm, while this explains what's going on, I don't agree with the explanation in full: JSON allows representing Unicode codepoints using four hex digits, but I haven't found any explicit mentioning of surrogate pairs. Anyhow, JSON is UTF-8 and since YAML is a superset thereof, you shouldn't have to escape these "special" characters, which should provide a workaround. The UTF-8 representation is `u"\ud83d\udcaf".encode('UTF-8')`, if you need the bytes or  if you just want the string.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added a link to the JSON RFC which mentions this.